# PHP Problem: Position Numbers Are Not Showing Correctly

Tags: php

I have the following code to enter the positions, etc.
I have two problems:

1. The position numbers show like 1, 2, 2, 2, 2 instead of 1, 2, 3, 4, 5
2. It would be "Days" even if the number of days is 1. I am uploading a screenshot.

Thank you very much for your input.
https://postimg.cc/mhQHqqyk

```
if (isset($_GET['boardcount']) && is_numeric($_GET['boardcount']) && $_GET['boardcount'] > 0) {
$boardcount = $_GET['boardcount'];
} else {
    $boardcount = 20;
}

$getleaderboard = lfmsql_query("SELECT a.days AS days, b.firstname AS firstname, b.lastname AS lastname, b.email AS email FROM `".$prefix."surftarget_logs` a LEFT JOIN `".$prefix."members` b ON (a.userid=b.Id) WHERE a.date='".$todaydate."' OR a.date='".$yesterdate."' ORDER BY a.days DESC") or die(lfmsql_error());

$position = 1;
$lastdays = 0;
$boardoutput = '';

while ($position <= $boardcount && $leaderlist = lfmsql_fetch_assoc($getleaderboard)) {



$gravatarimg = "https://www.gravatar.com/avatar/".md5($leaderlist['email'])."?d=mm";
    
    if (isset($_GET['usetable']) && $_GET['usetable'] > 0) {
    
    

$boardoutput .= '<tr><td style="background-color:#15aa00; padding: 15px; width:360px; color:#fff; border:solid; border-width: 1px 0; border-color:#fff;">
      <h5>#'.$position.' <img style="max-height:50px; max-width:50px;" src="'.$gravatarimg.'"> '.$leaderlist['firstname'].' '.$leaderlist['lastname'].'</h5>
      <span>'.$leaderlist['days'].' days</span>
      </td></tr>';
        
} else {
    $boardoutput .= '<li class="media list-group-item" style="background-color:#15aa00; color:#fff;">
<div class="media-body">
 

     <h5 class="mt-0 mb-1">#'.$position.' <img style="max-height:50px; max-width:50px;" src="'.$gravatarimg.'"> '.$leaderlist['firstname'].' '.$leaderlist['lastname'].'</h5>
      <p>'.$leaderlist['days'].' days</p>
    </div>
  </li>';
    }
    
    if ($leaderlist['days'] > $lastdays) {
        $position = $position + 1;
        $lastdays = $leaderlist['days'];
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This seems to be a logical bug in your code. As per the screenshot, it appears that it is not going inside the if block the second time onwards. you have to keep >= under if condition if you really want to increment them.

Modify this code:-

```
    if ($leaderlist['days'] > $lastdays) {
        $position = $position + 1;
        $lastdays = $leaderlist['days'];
    }
```

To:-

```
     if ($leaderlist['days'] >= $lastdays) {
        $position = $position + 1;
        $lastdays = $leaderlist['days'];
     }

Note:- >= symbol.
```

Comment: WOW, thank you very much indeed. It means a lot to me. How about the second problem? Can you please help me with that also?

Comment: the second one is just a text change. I think instead of days, it will be "day" (2 day , 3 day?) because nouns used as quantity in an attributive sense to describe another noun are singular.

Comment: Can't it be 1 day, 2 days, 3 days, etc.?

Comment: yeah, as per my understanding this is not correct from the grammar perspective. if you are specifying the length then "days" are fine eg:- This work will take 10 days, However, in your example, it appears that you are just attributing them isn't it? I am not a grammar expert though, however, if this is the requirement from your product owner then you can go and make the changes. :) just you have to adjust an if condition before displaying that specific text.